# Url rewriting mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using this tester for url  mod_rewrite test:
http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

When I write something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^x/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ x.php?x=$2
```

Even though I have entered url :

```
x/p/6/
```

It get renamed to

```
x.php?x=p
```

and. What I want is

```
x.php?x=6
```

I'm new with mod rewrite, so anything would be useful.

Comment: Your rule is correct. You have to test correctness of the rule on actual working Apache server and not on some 3rd party service which does not actually work as it should. And, BTW, you should leave at least some feedback to your previous questions and not just asking new question leaving previous behind without any comments/explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a pro in mod_rewrite myself, but I think there is something wrong with that tool. 
for example, if you change `x.php?x=$2` to `x.php?$1=$2`, `$2` will be parsed correctly.
And then, CMIIW but the regex looks fine. Test the regex [here](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) or [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).
And Have you ever actually tried the RewriteRule yourself?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^x/([a-z\/]+?)/([0-9]+)/$ x.php?x=$2
```

This adds all / characters to the first regex block. The ? makes the search non-greedy.